# Criando app Básico que abre um url

Tags: app

Já mexi um pouco nesses sites que oferecem "app gratuitos" e alguns desses sites tem um recurso bom pra mim!

Eles criam um app que funciona com uma url especifica, como se o app fosse apenas um navegador "travado" em um site especifico!

Acho que não expliquei muito bem, porém se alguém entendeu, será que poderia me dizer +/- como se faz isso?

Quero Fazer um app baseado nessa ideia, porem básico mesmo, sem abas, sem nada! Gostaria apenas de "emular" o site dentro do app!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar um WebView

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });

    }

}
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

[Fonte e exemplos](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)